# C# MongoDB driver transactions on a single MongoDB instance

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 4.0.8 with C# driver 2.8.1 and I'm trying to implement `Transactions` in my project.
I copy-pasted the following code sample:

```
static async Task<bool> UpdateProducts()
{
    //Create client connection to our MongoDB database
    var client = new MongoClient(MongoDBConnectionString);

    //Create a session object that is used when leveraging transactions
    var session = client.StartSession();

    //Create the collection object that represents the "products" collection
    var products = session.Client.GetDatabase("MongoDBStore").GetCollection<Product>("products");

    //Clean up the collection if there is data in there
    products.Database.DropCollection("products");

    //Create some sample data
    var TV = new Product { Description = "Television", SKU = 4001, Price = 2000 };
    var Book = new Product { Description = "A funny book", SKU = 43221, Price = 19.99 };
    var DogBowl = new Product { Description = "Bowl for Fido", SKU = 123, Price = 40.00 };

    //Begin transaction
    session.StartTransaction(new TransactionOptions(
                                                    readConcern: ReadConcern.Snapshot,
                                                    writeConcern: WriteConcern.WMajority));

    try
    {
        //Insert the sample data 
        await products.InsertOneAsync(session, TV);
        await products.InsertOneAsync(session, Book);
        await products.InsertOneAsync(session, DogBowl);

        var filter = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<Product>().Empty;
        var results = await products.Find(filter).ToListAsync();

        //Increase all the prices by 10% for all products
        var update = new UpdateDefinitionBuilder<Product>().Mul<Double>(r => r.Price, 1.1);
        await products.UpdateManyAsync(session, filter, update); //,options);

        //Made it here without error? Let's commit the transaction
        session.CommitTransaction();

        //Let's print the new results to the console
        Console.WriteLine("Original Prices:\n");
        results = await products.Find<Product>(filter).ToListAsync();
        foreach (Product d in results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Product Name: {0}\tPrice: {1:0.00}", d.Description, d.Price));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error writing to MongoDB: " + e.Message);
        session.AbortTransaction();
    }
    return true;
}
```

But in the first `Insert` command, I'm getting this error:

```
Command insert failed:
Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos.
```

The [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) says that:

> Starting in version 4.0, MongoDB provides the ability to perform multi-document transactions against replica sets.

I don't have replicas in my project, I have only one database instance which is my primary one. If there a solution or a work-around I can use to implement `Transactions`? I have methods that update more than one collection and I really think it could save me time to use it.

Answer (score 2):

like the documentation says, transactions only work with replica sets. so you need to run your mongodb server as single node replica set. to achieve that, do the following steps...

**step 1:**
stop the mongodb server.

**step 2:**
add the `replication` setting to your **mongod.cfg** file. here's my own as an example

```
storage:
  dbPath: C:\DATA
  directoryPerDB: true
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path:  C:\DATA\log\mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1

replication:
   replSetName: MyRepSet
```

**step 3:** open up a mongodb shell and issue the following command to initiate the replica set.

```sh
rs.initiate()
```

**step 4:** restart mongod

---

on a side-note, if you'd like to write cleaner, more convenient transaction code like the following, check out my library [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities)

```cs
    using (var TN = new Transaction())
    {
         var author = new Author { Name = "one" };

         TN.Save(author);

         TN.Delete<Book>(book.ID);

         TN.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: See comment #2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238986/pymongo-transaction-errortransaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-a-replica-set/51239633?noredirect=1#comment101023166_51239633): You can start a replica set with one node for development purposes. Start a mongod —replSet <replsetname> then do rs.initiate() in the mongo shell. Be advised that this is not a recommended setup for a production environment.

Comment: @LiranFriedman i assumed you were using `mongod.cfg` file. it's essentially the same thing.