# Check MongoDB database instance is a replica set

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm writing tests for functions that use transactions.

[Transactions only work on replica sets or mongos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51238986/4653485):

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos', 'code': 20, 'codeName': 'IllegalOperation'}
```

I would like those tests to be skipped if the database is a standalone mongod instance.

How can I check from Python code (e.g. with a pymongo function) that I'm using an adequate environment?

I can configure the CI Pipeline to use a replica set. I can, and did, configure that on my machine. But I don't want those few tests to be a hassle for potential contributors, so I'd rather skip them.

Alternatively, I could catch the `OperationFailure` and try to ensure it is exactly the error above, not another `OperationFailure`, by matching the string, but this would be a sorry workaround.

---

Perhaps I could use something like

```
MongoClient('localhost', 27017).admin.command("replSetGetStatus")
```

Before going through a tough trial and error session, I'd be happy to get an informed advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to check if the MongoDB instance is a replica-set:

Every `mongod` instance has its own [local](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/local-database/index.html) database (`local` is the database name), which stores data used in the replication process, and other instance-specific data. The `system.replset` collection in the `local` database holds the replica set’s configuration object as its single document.

To view this configuration, issue `rs.conf()` from the `mongo` shell. You can also query this collection directly (see below code used in a method).

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient(url)
collection = client.local.system.replset
try:
    doc = collection.find()[0]
    print(doc['_id'])
    return True
except Exception as e:
    print("local.system.replset doesn't exist: " + str(e))
    return False
```

Note the code raises an exception if cursor is empty, i.e., when the `system.replset` collection doesn't exist in the `local` database and the query fails (and the query fails for a *standalone* instance).

In the code, the `doc['_id']` is the replica-set name.

Comment: Thanks. Why not just `return "system.replset" in client.local.list_collection_names()`?

Comment: Valid question. I'd like rely upon the fact that: _"local.system.replset holds the replica set’s configuration object as its single document."_. Somehow it sounds guaranteed to query that collection and see there is such document which refers to a replica-set's configuration.

Comment: In case of standalone, the cursor is empty, right? Why not `return bool(client.local.system.replset.find())`, which should return True iif the cursor is not empty?

Comment: It is worth trying with various queries and see the results are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```py
def is_replica_set():
    try:
        pymongo.MongoClient().admin.command("replSetGetStatus")
        return True
    except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
        return False


@pytest.mark.skipif(not is_replica_set(), reason="Replica set required")
def test_transaction():
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Send `{ismaster: 1}` command and follow the rules [here](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#type) for parsing the response.

Replica set node will have `setName` field set in the response.