# in standalone mode why does the mongo transaction is not rollbacking back

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm looking for way to execute multiple statement in mongodb in a transaction. All or nothing kind of scenario. To make it easy to understand

```
trxTest> db.users.find({})
[ { _id: ObjectId("64ad882f451d9a5fc930eeb7"), name: 'werain' } ]
trxTest>
```

I'm looking to insert the multiple documents and one of the document conflict the uniquenss key on name 'werain'

```
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017"))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    DB := client.Database("trxTest")
    coll1 := DB.Collection("users")

    session, err := client.StartSession()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer session.EndSession(context.Background())

    _, err = session.WithTransaction(context.Background(), func(ctx mongo.SessionContext) (interface{}, error) {
        _, err = coll1.InsertOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"name": "vikas"})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        fmt.Println("vikas is inserted")


        _, err = coll1.InsertOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"name": "sriram"})
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        fmt.Println("sriram is inserted")

        fmt.Println("inserting is werain again")
        _, err = coll1.InsertOne(context.Background(), bson.M{"name": "werain"}) // This is where the transaction should failed
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        fmt.Println("werain is inserted")
        return nil, nil
    }, nil)

   
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("got trx error", err)
    }
```

Here how the code looks
I was accepting the database would rollback my 2 entry for users with name "vikas" and "sriram"

but I see this

```
trxTest> db.users.find({})
[
  { _id: ObjectId("64ad882f451d9a5fc930eeb7"), name: 'werain' },
  { _id: ObjectId("64ad8c65f63f3f2b48f66169"), name: 'vikas' },
  { _id: ObjectId("64ad8c66f63f3f2b48f6616a"), name: 'sriram' }
]
```

Error

```
vikas is inserted
sriram is inserted
inserting is werain again

got error write exception: write errors: [E11000 duplicate key error collection: trxTest.users index: name_1 dup key: { name: "werain" }]
```

```
db version v6.0.1
Build Info: {
    "version": "6.0.1",
    "gitVersion": "32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "system",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "aarch64",
        "target_arch": "aarch64"
    }
}
```

Comment: Transactions are supported for replica sets. Are you running this against a replica set?

Comment: @BurakSerdar No standalone

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @burak-serdar, **Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos**. See also [PyMongo transaction error:Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51238986/pymongo-transaction-errortransaction-numbers-are-only-allowed-on-a-replica-set).

Besides that, the doc for the `WithTransaction` method of the [mongo.Session](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo#Session) interface states that

> Inside the callback, the SessionContext must be used as the Context parameter for any operations that should be part of the transaction.

So you should replace all the following calls

```golang
_, err = coll1.InsertOne(context.Background(), //...
```

with

```golang
_, err = coll1.InsertOne(ctx, //...
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, and not having access to Transactions (as pointed out by @Zeke Lu amd @Burak Serdar) your best option is to use a bulk operation like [Insert Many](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/)

This way, you'll get a `BulkWriteError` for the duplicate `_id` key, but all the others should insert. For this to work, use an unordered insertMany operation.

> ordered operations stop after an error, while unordered operations continue to process any remaining write operations in the queue